# Can I assign a device node to the mount point in /etc/fstab

Tags: linux, device, udev

Host: Ubuntu 14.10

I have one line in my `/etc/fstab` file shown in the following:

```
UUID=00e12ac3-210d-53te-91ca-82a11226d5c8 /media/laptop/SSD/ ext4 errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

This SSD has its device node which is `/dev/sda`.

Is it possible to change it from `/dev/sda` to `/dev/sdb` in `/etc/fstab` file ?

If so, how can I modify it ?

Comment: This really belongs in this sysadmin site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel assigns the device number when it detects the device. So when the first device that looks like a 'scsi disk' (sd) is detected, it is assigned the device-number (8, 0) and is thus /dev/sda.  When the second is detected, it is (8, 16) and so on.

```
# ls -l /dev/sd[ab]
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  0 Dec  6  2014 /dev/sda
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 16 Dec  6  2014 /dev/sdb
```

You could, **at your own risk!**, swap the `/dev/sda[ab]*` entries, so they looked something like this:

```
# ls -l /dev/sd[ab]
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 16 Jan 19  2016 /dev/sda
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  8 Jan 19  2016 /dev/sdb
```

but I don't recommend that kind of hanky-panky unless you **really** know what you are doing and what all the possible ramifications are.

Instructions:

```
(su / sudo / login as root)
# cd /dev

# ls -l sd[ab]*
Note the device numbers, they may be different from mine!

Remove existing
# rm sd[ab]*

Make again with swapped minor device numbers
# mknod sda b 8 16
# mknod sda1 b 8 17
# mknod sdb b 8 0
# mknod sdb1 b 8 1

(you may need to alter your boot config, grub or whatever)
# reboot
```

Again, I stress this is at your own risk, I have no idea what on your system this could effect.

Comment: Would you please to give the instruction in your post ?